# Jmeter with Maven Plugin , Threads are getting hung/not responding in distributed tests

Tags: multithreading, maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am currently running Distributed tests with Jmeter Maven Plugin. Everything Works fine some times [when Less Users/threads are specified] . But when i run Tests with 50 users per node , all threads gets hung/not responding in nodes.

Tried increasing -xms and xmx in JVM , still see the issue.

And one thing i observed is , after running the load test , all threads were hung. I killed Jmeter-server on both nodes and restared with just 2 users . Even for 2 users , threads are getting hung after running load test.

Is there any solution for this ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Again my answer was deleted, so I'll add it as a comment.  It sounds like you are suffering from this bug: https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/108 It's fixed in 1.10.1. The workaround in earlier versions is to set the configuration option:

<suppressJMeterOutput>false</suppressJMeterOutput>

Answer (score 0):

Before switching to maven/jenkins did you try launching the distributed test with hust jmeter ?

What are the versions you are using for each of the components.